# Create , add rows and delete rows from Table in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to make a dynamic table in Flutter/Dart where I can add new rows , delete some of them and edit their content .

I tried different packages but I couldn't figure out a way to make it .

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What do you mean dynamic table? Will the columns be changed at runtime?

Comment: Before asking questions here search for it in google. I am pretty sure there are plenty of tutorials on how to add, remove and update rows dynamically into a table in flutter. For your reference check out this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6yndJ_lk14